# A question related to Push Notification

Tags: iphone

iphone developers
i'm in tremendous trouble
1>I know how to set badge number in apple push Notification.
  but i don't know how to get the badge number if it is set by os
I need badge count in applicationdidfinishlaunching

Comment: I need badge count in applicationdidfinishlaunching

Comment: Yes you said that above, in the question

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get it from

```
application.applicationIconBadgeNumber
```

Comment: if i press home and then i call applicationdidfinishlaunching,i will not get it through application.applicationIconBadgeNumber